# What's the difference between the different import locations for `RequestHandler` type in SvelteKit

Tags: typescript, sveltekit

What's the difference between

```js
import type { RequestHandler } from "@sveltejs/kit";
```

and

```js
import type { RequestHandler } from "./__types";
```

When I hover over `RequestHandler`, I see different type definitions in VS code, but I can't parse what's really going on.

Comment: `"./__types"` seems to be a file in your project. Did you create this file?

Comment: No, I'm looking at [these docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/types#generated-types) which say something about it.